# How do you disable strict errors for PHP 5.4 & 5.5 in Drupal 7 via the settings.php file?

Tags: 7

Currently I disabled the error messages via UI under Administration > Developement > Logging & Errors:

[image: Screenshot]

But I want to be able to do this via the settings.php file. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

And the Drupal way:

Add this line in settings.php

```
$conf['error_level'] = 0; // 0: None, 1: Errors and warnings, 2: All messages
```

You can set any persistent variable this way. You can get the variable names simply using Firebug or any browser's developer tool and check the `name` attribute of the input field in the administration form. Which in you case the Logging & Errors page. If you look at the source code, the radio buttons have the `name` attribute `error_level` and each radio button has a `value` attribute. Simply set this value to the variable in you settings.php using `$conf` array.

You can also set any variable using [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) function in any custom module, in an update script for example.

Or using Drush:

```
drush vset error_level 0
```

Comment: I set the error_level to: 1 (errors & warnings) ... and those strict errors arent showing now even after a clear cache. But now the question is what does "errors & warnings" encompass? I dont want to supress other errors that i might want to know about.

Comment: If I look at the code of [`error_displayable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21errors.inc/function/error_displayable/7) function, I see that if you set it to 1, it will display only the errors whose types are NOT 'Notice' AND NOT 'Strict warning'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code on your settings.php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

or

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

Note: E_STRICT has only been part of E_ALL since php 5.4

http://php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

Check if adding the following at the begging of the settings.php works:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 30711);
```

that will affect the PHP settings for your site.

Comment: does that only disable the "strict errors" and nothing else? Where did you find that 30711 code? thanks.

Comment: In PHP, all the predefined constants from that are for error handling have a numeric value assigned. You can find more info at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758418/numeric-values-of-error-reporting-levels#3758466

Answer (score 0):

Drupal seems to override the setting.php

The best answers I found so far are the ones in that thread: [Remove the strict warnings from being shown](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99947/remove-the-strict-warnings-from-being-shown)

Either you go hide the warnings in drupal interface:

*This will hide everything, but occuring problems will still be logged, and hiding might be a good solution for a production environment anyway*.

Or you directly modify the Drupal error handler:

 *This is the solution I chose, which is more focused on the need.  The only drawback I see is that the operation might have to be done again when updating drupal version.*

btw, avoid using lines like `ini_set('error_reporting', 30711);`

 error and warning values use mask for readibility, so, you'd better use something like `(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING)` than any crude number value